ASP.NET Core : passing my session / authentication login in localStorage
I am trying to pass the email and username to the localStorage so I can use it in my dashboard and to logout the account. I'm not very familiar so much with ASP.NET since the setup was too complicated to find in Google. Of course I used chatgpt resources to able to make it but I can't with much complicated areas.
I have a Controller/AuthController.cs so you will see the all the authentication here for login.
Login attempt #1
The first one is to pass the Json but the problem with it in frontend in Login.cshtml it's not passing the localStorageItem I wanted to pass and not also redirecting.
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, message = "Invalid login attempt." });
        }

        var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == model.Email);

        if (user == null || !VerifyPasswordHash(model.Password, user.Password))
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, message = "Invalid login attempt." });
        }

        // Store user info in session
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserEmail", user.Email);
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserName", user.Username);

        // Return a JSON response with user details
        return Json(new { success = true, email = user.Email, username = user.Username });
    }

.cshtml view:
 <script>
    document.getElementById('loginButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
        // Fetch email and password from the form
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var password = document.getElementById('password').value;

        // Prepare data to send in POST request
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('Email', email);
        formData.append('Password', password);

        // Send AJAX request to login endpoint
        fetch('/Authentication/Login', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        })
            .then(response => response.json()) // Parse JSON response
            .then(data => {
                if (data.success) {
                    // If login successful, save user data in localStorage
                    localStorage.setItem('userEmail', data.email);
                    localStorage.setItem('userName', data.username);

                    // Log for debugging purposes
                    console.log("User session saved in localStorage.");

                    // Optionally, redirect or update UI here
                } else {
                    // Display error message
                    var loginMessage = document.getElementById('loginMessage');
                    loginMessage.innerText = data.message;
                    loginMessage.style.display = 'block';
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error during login:', error);
            });
    });
</script>

Login attempt 2
This one is working redirecting with the Dashboard but not also able to save the localStorage:
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Console.WriteLine("Model state is invalid during login attempt.");
            return View("~/Views/Authentication/Login.cshtml", model);
        }

        var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == model.Email);
        if (user == null || !VerifyPasswordHash(model.Password, user.Password))
        {
            // Console.WriteLine($"Invalid login attempt for email: {model.Email}");
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View("~/Views/Authentication/Login.cshtml", model);
        }

        // Store user info in session
        HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserEmail");
        HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserName");
        // Console.WriteLine($"User {model.Email} logged in successfully.");

        // Pass session data to the view via ViewBag
        ViewBag.UserEmail = user.Email;
        ViewBag.UserName = user.Username;

        // return;
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
    }

.cshtml view:
<script>
    // Use ViewBag values passed from the controller
    var userEmail = '@ViewBag.UserEmail';
    var userName = '@ViewBag.UserName';

    if (userEmail && userName) {
        // Store session info in localStorage
        localStorage.setItem("userEmail", userEmail);
        localStorage.setItem("userName", userName);

        // Optionally, you can log the stored data
        console.log("User session saved in localStorage.");
    } else {
        console.log("No session data found to save.");
    }
</script>

I can saved the cookie but not the session or localStorage

and this is my Program.cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Auth.Data; // Reference to your Data folder

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

// Add session management services with some configuration for session timeout, etc.
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30); // Set session timeout duration
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;  // Make session cookies HTTP-only for security
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;  // Ensure session cookie is available even if GDPR opt-out is active
});

// Add database context using MySQL
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseMySql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), ServerVersion.AutoDetect(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))));

var app = builder.Build();

// Use session middleware, which is necessary for session management
app.UseSession();
...


If i understood your problem right, it seems you are trying to login and save the session of this logged in user through local storage in order to access it again, now i don't really recommend handling authentication through local storage, but in your problem here if your sole goal is to logout the user when its done you can always just clear the session you set when the user logged in using:
HttpContext.Session.Clear();

this will clear the Session that has the user email and username saved then you can redirect the user to the login page after logging out.
If you need to access the strings you set the useremail and username you can use:
HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserEmail");

this will retrieve the useremail saved to the session in your controller.
for your local storage problem, you seem to setting the items normally using:
localStorage.setItem('userEmail', data.email);
localStorage.setItem('userName', data.username);

the problem should not be with setting the items, maybe your model state is invalid the way you are sending the form data check the binding with the loginViewModel if the state is not valid the response is probably returning "false". However if the message you set saying:
console.log("User session saved in localStorage.");

is showing up normally you might be clearing the local storage somewhere in the process. try clearing the cache of the application and checking the code then trying again, but according to the info provided it is mainly an error on the model controller side.
I recommend Using a cookie authentication scheme or a token in any way for good security posture for example in your configuration you can use:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()

then you can set all your desired options in the cookie and use claims for roles and permissions with policies which are great and flexible, you should look them up.

Hi, thanks for the comment but where part of attempt codes you are talking to? Plus I also have the ViewBag which is actually I don't know how to works is it necessary you think? also I tried different things there is no really error coming out in my console in website. So I'm looking different way to solve this but I couldn't because it keeps erasing the localStorage or session but the cookieSession is being save.

@XenexAshura, Since you are planning on using local storage no need for view bags, view bags are data holders that are not persistant so you lose them after refresh they are no really useful here even if to save into local storage.
In login attempt #2 why did you change setString to getString you need the setString in order to see the value in local storage in the application tab of the developer tools.
in attempt #1 you are returning a json that tracks the state and there is no redirection for the page to redirect, check if it is reaching the success=true, and add redirection logic in js.

Before answering your question, I would like to clarify these concepts with you:
Session state (HttpContext.Session): Store data on server side and a session cookie is specific to the browser, you can check the session expiration via the session cookie (F12 => Application => Cookies). The session data persistent across multiple browser windows and tabs as long as the session cookie is present and valid.
LocalStorage: Store data on client side (browser), the data persistent across all browser windows, tabs, and sessions. The data has no expiration time it remains until manually cleared by the user or code. Note it is less secure.
ViewBag/ViewData: Used to pass data from Controller to View (only available for the current request).
TempData: Used to pass data from Controller to View or Across Requests (persists for the next request).

Login attempt #1
The first one is to pass the Json but the problem with it in frontend
in Login.cshtml it's not passing the localStorageItem I wanted to pass
and not also redirecting.

For this attempt, using your code, you could store the UserName and UserEmail in session and local storage. You can check it via the following steps:
Session cookie: By default, the session cookie is start as .AspNetCore.Session. The AntiForgery cookie stores the AntiForgery token, when using FormTagHelper (<form>) in asp.net core, it will auto use a AntiForgery cookie to store the token. More detail information, see Prevent Cross-Site Request Forgery (XSRF/CSRF) attacks in ASP.NET Core

LocalStorage: in my sample, I just store the UserName, so the output like this:

From about the screenshot, if the response is success, after store data in the localstorage, we can use window.location.href property to navigate to another page, code like this:
    if (data.success) {
        // If login successful, save user data in localStorage 
        localStorage.setItem('userName', data.userName);
        console.log(data.message);
        // navigate to another page
        location.href="/Home/Privacy"
    } else {
        console.log(data.message);
        // Handle error (e.g., display validation messages)
    }


Login attempt 2
This one is working redirecting with the Dashboard but not also able to save the :localStorage

Based on the ViewBag usage range, since you'll be redirecting to the Index action method, if you set a breakpoint in the Index method, you can see that the ViewBag is null and you can't use it to pass data across controllers.
To pass data between action methods, in the Login Post method, you can store the data in session, and then in the Index action method, get data from session first and then set the ViewBag again, after that you can get the data in the Index view page.
Finally, using your method for authentication, we store the user's identity, claims, and expiration time in local storage, and in subsequent HTTP requests, we must first read the data from the local storage and verify that it is valid. In addition, local storage is not secure and can lead to security issues.
Generally, we recommend use cookie authentication. It is easier to configurator and after login success via the HttpContext.SignInAsync() method, it will auto create a cookie to store the user's identifiable information, in the subsequent HTTP requests, browser will auto add the cookie to the request header. On the server side, we can just add the Authorize attribute to protect the resource.
To cookie authentication in Asp.Net Core application, you can configure CookieAuthenticationOptions in the AddCookie method:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Forbidden/";
    });

enable Authentication and Authorization middleware:
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

In the Login method, refer to the following code to use HttpContext.SignInAsync() method.
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string username, string password, string ReturnUrl)
    {
        if ((username == "Admin") && (password == "Admin"))
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username)
            };
            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Login");

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity));
            return Redirect(ReturnUrl == null ? "/Secured" : ReturnUrl);
        }
        else
            return View();
    }

And in the protect action method, add Authorize attribute as below.
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Privacy()
    { 
        return View();
    }

More detail information, refer the following links:
Use cookie authentication without ASP.NET Core Identity
How to Implement Cookie Authentication in ASP.NET Core
